# ngSubmit is not triggering function in controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-submit

I am relatively very new to AngularJS and javascript Please be merciful while answering.

I am trying to create one sample application where  I want to nest controllers. MainController which will always be there acting as parent container which will render menu and user name on top if user is logged in. For now I am checking if user is stored in localStorage.

Each page will have its own controller which will do page specific things.

I am stuck at ng-submit and why its not working?

Any help is appreciated.

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="angularapp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myAngularApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-show="isLoggedIn">Menu</div>
        <div ng-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

login.html

```
  <from ng-submit="login()">
    <input type="text" id="username" ng-model="username"></input>
    <input type="password" id="password" ng-model="password"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" ng-submit="login()"></input>
</form>
```

angularapp.js

```
angular.module('myAngularApp',['ngRoute','ngResource'])
.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider.when('/home',{
        controller:'SubController',
        templateUrl:'templates/home.html'
    })
    .when('/login',{
        controller:'MainController',
        templateUrl:'templates/login.html'
    });
}])
.controller('MainController',['$scope','$window','userService',function($scope,$window,userService){
    $scope.isLoggendIn=userService.isLoggedIn;
    console.log('here I come');
    $scope.username='';
    $scope.password='';
    $scope.login=function(){
        alert('Ignored???');
        $window.localStorage['myUser']={username:$scope.username,password:$scope.password};
        consoel.log('user is logged in now');
    };
}])
.controller('SubController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.myContent='Contenst to show after logged in';
}])
.service('userService',['$window',function($window){
    var self=this;  
    self.isLoggedIn=function(){
        if($window.localStorage['myUser'])
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    };
}]);
```

Comment: You have different functions there  ng-submit="submit()" , ng-submit="login()"

Comment: Thanks u  @ElvinValiev I tried changing  submit to login. still not working. all the places in login.html and angularapp.js also.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, you also have to change ng-submit to ng-click in your submit input.

Comment: Please check my answer.Surely you will get your error resolved.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change your code. Seems you have made spelling mistake.

```
<from ng-submit="submit()">
```

to:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
```

Also replace the following code.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" ng-click="submit()"></input>
```

Comment: That's not the only typo in the code, OP should be more careful and it's scary only you noticed that ;)

Comment: @DilipN thanks a lot....!!! May be u really need outsiders view to get things right. wasted 4 hours on this :( do u suggest any tool to increase productivity in html & angular?

Comment: I use 2 different editors, paid WebStorm from JetBrains and Atom from Git, both have live validation of code and good support of angular

Comment: BTW you don't need the `ng-click` on input as the submit would trigger `ng-submit` anyway

Comment: It's been over 3 yrs, can you believe the "<from .." is still sitting there (in 2 answers and the question). Must be a gem! I can change it, but I think somebody might need a laugh!

Answer (score 1):

No need of  `ng-submit="login()"` in this place `type="submit` is enought and last one is `button` not `input`

```
<from ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" id="username" ng-model="username"></input>
    <input type="password" id="password" ng-model="password"></input>
    <button type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment to functionality

Comment: sorry @maurycy I don't have privilege to comment out.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" ng-submit="login()"></input>
```

Must be as below:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" ng-click="submit()"></input>
```

Comment: `ng-submit` shouldn't even be there, the `input#type:submit` should trigger the `ng-submit` on form

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in your login.html. remove login() because you have submit()

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" id="username" ng-model="username"></input>
    <input type="password" id="password" ng-model="password"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: It's been over 3 yrs, <from is still there .. in the question, and 2 answers   LMAO...